# Is there a way to provide Flux to a WebClient's body as a Form Data?

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I want to use WebClient to access some restricted resource so it requires login and password to be provided and encoded as form data. It works just fine like that

```
private Mono<MyDataType> getMyDataType() {
    return WebClient.builder().build().post()
            .uri(MY_URI)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
            .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(getFormData()))
            .exchange()
            .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(MyDataType.class));
}

private MultiValueMap<String, String> getFormData() {
    MultiValueMap<String, String> credentials = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
    credentials.add("login", readLoginStringFromDiskAsString);
    credentials.add("password", readPasswordStringFromDiskAsString);
}
```

However, my `read*` functions are, as you can see, blocking - simple `Files.readAllBytes`, as you would do in any other app. 
I'd like to transition this reading from disk to something more asynchronous, like use DataBufferUtils or something similar. Problem is, Spring only provides one implementation of `fromFormData` - `fromFormData(MultiValueMap<String, String> formData)`.

Is there a way to actually achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

You could change your `getFormData` method to return `Mono<MultiValueMap<String, String>>` and flat map its result to access credentials asynchronously

```
private Mono<MultiValueMap<String, String>> getFormDataNonBlocking() {
    //asynchronous nonblocking reading of the credentials
}

private Mono<MyDataType> getMyDataType() {
    return getFormDataNonBlocking()
            .flatMap(credentials -> WebClient.builder()
                    .build()
                    .post()
                    .uri(MY_URI)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
                    .body(BodyInserters.fromFormData(credentials))
                    .exchange()
                    .flatMap(clientResponse -> clientResponse.bodyToMono(MyDataType.class)));
}
```

There is one note. You shouldn't create new `WebClient` for each request. Use predefined `WebClient.Builder` bean from Spring Boot or reuse one instance of your own.

Comment: Unfortunately it'll probably not be a `Mono<MultiValueMap<String, String>>`, rather a `MultiValueMap<String, Flux<String>>` which is a pain in the ass to work with.